# Why FourierSequenceTransform cannot be applied to a List (discrete samples) of data?

Tags: fourier-analysis

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform) says the following:

> In mathematics, the discrete-time Fourier transform (DTFT) is a form of Fourier analysis that is applicable to a sequence of discrete values.
> …
> The DTFT itself is a continuous function of frequency, but discrete samples of it can be readily calculated via the discrete Fourier transform (DFT) (see § Sampling the DTFT), which is by far the most common method of modern Fourier analysis.

Meanwhile in Mathematica [FourierSequenceTransform](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FourierSequenceTransform.html) (which actually produce DTFT) can only be applied to expression. The latter cannot be a List of data, but has to be some continous function.
So my question is - why is that? :-)
In my qualitative understanding, we should use DTFT if we are interested in synthesis of the original signal too, no only in Fourier analysis. In other words, if after the analysis we want to reconstruct the original signal from its samples, we have to use DTFT. But if all we need is the spectrum of the data, we are okay with DFT.

p.s.: what's more interesting is that FourierSequenceTransform does not even have SampleRate option, which is possess such Mathematica functions like ContinousWaveletTransfrom or ShortTimeFourier...

Comment: Do you know about the function [`Fourier`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fourier.html) which takes in a discrete list?

Comment: @Domen
of course I do. ANd use it a lot. But what I do NOT know is the necessity of FourierSequenceTransform. When I really supposed to use it?

Comment: Okay then, do you also know about [`ListFourierSequenceTransform`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListFourierSequenceTransform.html)?

Comment: @Domen
I don’t even know how I managed to miss this.. Thank you :-)